# Is there a Meta Key for variable products? (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to integrate Woocommerce Simple Auctions with WP Frontend pro to let users upload products from a front end form. This works great for simple products, but simple auctions gives an variable called auctions. I have set all the meta keys the auctionplugin gives, but I still hav to go to the backend and press update for it to actually become an auction.

Is there a meta key that sets the product to a variable one instead of simple, or is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: `product_type` is a [custom taxonomy](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L45-55) on the product post type. So it is the term 'variable' in this taxonomy that makes a product variable. Though child posts (aka variations) are then required.